# How to update description fields in jira4r gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jira

I'm able to update the custom-field of a jira-ticket by using the following code.

```
a = Jira4R::V2::RemoteFieldValue.new
a.id = "customfield_10000"
a.values = 'blah'

b = Jira4R::V2::RemoteFieldValue.new
b.id = "customfield_10022"
b.values = 'test'

ticket = jira.getIssue('blah-105')
jira.updateIssue(ticket.key, [a, b])
```

However, I am unable to update the description field using the same method.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error or is it ignored silently?

Comment: i tried ` jira.updateIssue(ticket.description,"update value field")` got ,  Finding method update<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x43798c8>: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found
a inside an array element while deserializing (SOAP::FaultError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found simple solution.

```
a = Jira4R::V2::RemoteFieldValue.new
a.id = "description" #id of description field
a.values = 'custom value'
ticket = jira.getIssue('TST-164')
jira.updateIssue(ticket.key, [a])
```